# when i try to register with JSONArrayRequest

Tags: java, android

i get this message com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Email of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObjectError
i din't get any Response..

JsonObjectRequest jsr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, params, new Response.Listener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Response");
                                }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error + "Error");
                if( error instanceof ParseError) {

                }

            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
           /**
         * Set Time duration for Register Screen and and put JsonObjectRequest in volley RequestQueue Class.
         * and take action according to RequestQueue Class.
                */
                jsr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registers.this);
            requestQueue.add(jsr);
            break;

    }
    }
```

when i try to registerwith StringRequest i get this message in Backend..

WARN 10024 --- [nio-6060-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Unrecognized token 'phoneno': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

```
            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG,response.toString());
                        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            params.put("name", finalNAME);
                            params.put("email", finalMail);
                            params.put("city", finalCITY);
                            params.put("password", finalPASSWORD);
                            params.put("phoneno", finalMobile);

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
            },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG,error.toString());
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("city", finalCITY);
                    params.put("email", finalMail);
                    params.put("name", finalNAME);
                    params.put("password", finalPASSWORD);
                    params.put("phoneno", finalMobile);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   *//* params.put("name", finalNAME1);
                    params.put("email", finalMail1);
                    params.put("city", finalCITY);
                    params.put("password", finalPASSWORD);
                    params.put("phoneno", finalMobile);
                   *//* params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registers.this);
            requestQueue.add(sr);
            break;
    }}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why creating JsonObject at onResponse?

Comment: i am trying to to create String at onResponse but i get syntax error

Comment: You are doing some wrong implementation.
You will get API response at onResponse and from there you should parse response as per requirement and after that create new Json based on response.

Comment: i don't understand when i user JSONObjectrequest i got response from server com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Email of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObjectError but i see in backend it will register then i don't understand how to handle it

Comment: Can you send your response so i can help on that ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me i have solve it